# Can't get my custom controls to appear in intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, custom-server-controls

I have added my assembly and namespace to my project, but I cannot get intellisense to show my tag name in the ASP.NET markup. What am I missing?

I have a project that is MyWebSite.Web.

In my web.config I have:

```
      <controls>
       ...
        <add tagPrefix="MyTagName" namespace="Enhancements.Controls" assembly="Enhancements" />
      </controls>
```

I have a project called Enhancements, and inside that project I have a class file with the namespace Enhancements.Controls.

When I go to my web project, I get no intellisense on my controls.

Is there anything in particular to look for as far as why or ways to track this down?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the web project have a reference to the Enhancements project? I use the same syntax in my web.config without issue.